# Arquillian: Attempted to register the same Observer, ServerSetupObserver multiple times

Tags: junit, ejb, cdi, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to configure arquillian with wildfly but am the following Getting error in the process of running test:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:165).......
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ...........
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:165)
    at .................
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at ...............
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create and process manager
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:105)......
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to register the same Observer: org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ServerSetupObserver multiple times, please check classpath for conflicting jar versions
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl$2.observer(ManagerImpl.java:354)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.LoadableExtensionLoader$1.observer(LoadableExtensionLoader.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonContainerExtension.register(CommonContainerExtension.java:41)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.remote.RemoteContainerExtension.register(RemoteContainerExtension.java:33)
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <!-- build details -->
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <build_version>${project.version}</build_version>
        <build_number>00001</build_number>
        <!-- dependency version variables -->
        <struts2.version>2.3.24</struts2.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <resteasy.version>3.0.11.Final</resteasy.version>
        <apache.common.version>3.3.2</apache.common.version>
        <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
        <arquillian-version>1.1.8.Final</arquillian-version>
        <arquillian-transaction-version>1.0.1.Final</arquillian-transaction-version>
        <arquillian-wildfly-version>8.2.0.Final</arquillian-wildfly-version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss Repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- -JUNIT-->
            <dependency>
               <groupId>junit</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
               <version>${junit-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Arquillian itself-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${arquillian-version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <!-- this is in an extention to arquillian it is optional-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${arquillian-transaction-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- this is container adapter for wildfly-->
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
               <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
               <version>${arquillian-wildfly-version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-jta</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- struts 2 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
           <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the CDI API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-cdi-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jboss weld -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <finalName>fms</finalName>
            <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in your 
                Wildfly instance -->
            <!-- This profile will start a new Wildfly instance, and execute the 
                test, shutting it down when done -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                  <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.0.Alpha5</version>
                  <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in a remote 
                Wildfly instance -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                  <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.0.Alpha5</version>
                  <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <properties>
                <env>development</env>
                <fms.restws.url>http://localhost:8080/fms/rs/json</fms.restws.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <env>prod</env>
                <fms.restws.url>http://prodserver:8080/fms/rs/json</fms.restws.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

GreeterTest.java

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class) public class GreeterTest {

@Inject
Greeter greeter;

@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "fms-tes.war")
            .addClass(Greeter.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}

@Test
public void should_create_greeting() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertEquals("Hello, Earthling!",greeter.createGreeting("Earthling"));
    greeter.greet(System.out, "Earthling");
} }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the dependencyManagement and dependency definition for org.wildfly:wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded. You have setup profiles using the org.wildfly.arquillian:xxxx adaptors as well. They are technically very similar but are intended for two different versions of the WildFly server. Being based on the same code base they both attempt to register the same observers.