# Conflict on IntelliJ's classpath?

Tags: intellij-idea, classpath, jboss-arquillian

I get this nice exception when trying to run my tests with Arquillian:

```
Internal Error occured.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:93)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.ManagerBuilder.create(ManagerBuilder.java:77)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:55)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create and process manager
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:104)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to register the same Observer: org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ServerSetupObserver multiple times, please check classpath for conflicting jar versions
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl$2.observer(ManagerImpl.java:323)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.LoadableExtensionLoader$1.observer(LoadableExtensionLoader.java:100)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonContainerExtension.register(CommonContainerExtension.java:41)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.remote.RemoteContainerExtension.register(RemoteContainerExtension.java:33)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.LoadableExtensionLoader.load(LoadableExtensionLoader.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fireProcessing(ManagerImpl.java:316)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:98)
... 28 more
```

I'm aware of [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313176/arquillian-attempted-to-register-the-same-observer-serversetupobserver-multipl) and that `ServerSetupObserver` exists probably in multiple versions in my classpath. The difference in my case is that if I run my tests from an ant target, then they're completely fine, I only get this error when running the tests from IntelliJ.

The question is: how can I check where exactly does IntelliJ put `ServerSetupObserver` class on the classpath and/or how can I remove it from there? (Or what else can be the issue here?)

Comment: Are you using IDEA's Arquillian plugin? If so please try without and let me know if there is still something to investigate. I will be happy to help.

Comment: @bartosz.majsak: yes, I use the Arquillian plugin. I can't try it again, because I solved my main issue meanwhile, but if I remember correctly running the tests without it just as a simple JUnit target had problems too.

Comment: Aaand I just had the very same issue again. I tried without the Arquillian plugin, and the error message I get is the very same.

Comment: What is the output of `mvn dependency:tree`? Do you have multiple versions of Arquillian libraries included? Assuming that you are using Maven of course :)

Comment: not using maven, using ant. (I have an ant target for these tests too, but that runs fine. only IntelliJ's classpath is messed up)

Comment: Seems like some specific IDEA issue then. Honestly I have no idea what might be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but my workaround:

I needed to remove all dependencies from all of the modules and add only the needed dependencies again. With a project of this size this would have been even more troublesome as it was, but luckily the project also has guys who use Eclipse and their classpaths were okay, so I could use the [Eclipse Dependency Sync](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/949?pr=) plugin to get my dependencies back from them.